# Odd list and index behaviour

Tags: python, list, function, range

I'm trying to write a simple script to conjugate verbs in a list of words.
I have a list of lists of lists like this one:

```
expressions = [[['battre', 'verb', 'inf', True],  ['froid', 'adj', 'ms', 'False']], [['prendre', 'verb', 'inf', True], ['froid', 'adj', 'ms', False]]]
```

"True" means it's variable, and "False" means it shoudn't change.
For each elem in each list of this list, i find the ones with the tag "verb", and build a matching flexions list. For example, for the expression "battre froid", I'll take "battre", and build a list with all French flexions of the verb. I'll end up with something like

```
verbs = ['bat', 'bats', 'battons'..].
```

What I wanna do next is, for one given expression such as "battre froid", build a list of all possible flexions of this expression, such as "bats froid", "battons froid", etc.
I should then end up with something like

```
res = [[['battons', 'verb', '3pPres'], ['froid', 'adj', 'ms']], ['bats', 'v', '2sPres'],['froid', 'adj', 'ms]]]
```

See, my problem is not about the building itself, it's about the result changing depending on where I call it from. And I can't seem to be able to identify why it behaves differently.

All I do next is this:

```
idx = 0 (position in the list of the verb in one expression, here 0)
for i in range(len(verbs)):
    expressions[i][idx] = verbs[i]  ## replacing infinitive form by conjugated one

return res
```

And for some obscure reason, this is what happens:
All verbs are replaced with the last flexion found in the verbs list.
BUT, that is, ONLY when this bit of code is called from within a function.
When printing during execution, I see exactly what I want. But at the end, I get something different.
Bigger problem is, I checked loops, I checked the data right BEFORE and during the exec of these lines of code in the function, it's all good.
I even copy-pasted the data in the function from my terminal after printing it and redid the same bit of code (the "for i in range part) at the end of my script (out of a function), and I got exactly what I wanted.

It only seems to fail when done from within a function. I've been stuck on this for two days, comparing lists, copy-pasting, moving code around, checking types, repr, prints... I just don't get why it's behaving this way inside a function. And I need it in this function unfortunately...

Here's the code, where expr_listFormat is the same as "expressions", and flexDict is a flexions dictionary (key is a base and values are flexions of the base):

EDIT ON ORIGINAL CODE:

```
def createVariants(expr_listFormat, flexDict):
    for sublist in expr_listFormat:
        if sublist[3] and sublist[1] == "v":
            verbFlex = []  ## list of flexions, each flexion being a tuple like ('bats', 'v', '2s')
            resList = []  ## list of copies of the expression
        for flexion in flexDict[sublist[0]]:
            resList.append(expr_listFormat)  ## making a copy of the original for each flexion
            verbFlex.append(flexion)  ## list of flexions
        for i in range(len(verbFlex)):
            resList[i][idx] = verbFlex[i]
    return resList
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working (or more precisely, why it's only working outside of a function, and until the last for loop inside the function) ?

When I print resList and verbFlex before the last for loop, copy-paste them, and redo the range bit outside, it works just fine... I don't get it :(

Thanks so much, and sorry for the long post, I was tring to be as precise and clear as I could !

Cheers

Xhattam

Comment: Is `expr_listFormat` a list of lists of strings, or a list of lists of lists of strings? What exactly is `flexDict`? Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code and input data? Note that `resList.append(expr_listFormat)` **does not**, whatever the comment might claim, make a copy.

Comment: Is your last code snippet correctly indented (I mean: is it the exact same indentation as in your original code) ?

Comment: In your last snippet of code, it seems your second for loop miss an indentation. (like @bruno-desthuilliers suggested)

Comment: Hi again, here are the missing information:  the dictionary flexDic for the expression "battre sa coulpe" is like this:  flexDic:

{u'sa': set([(u'sa', 'det', '3s')]), u'coulpe': [u'coulpe', u'nc', u'fs', False], 'battre': set([(u'battiez', 'v', '2p'), (u'battrez', 'v', '2p'), (u'battant', 'v', '@G'), (u'battent', 'v', '3p'), (u'battions', 'v', '1p'), (u'battre', 'v', '@W'), (u'battez', 'v', '2p'), (u'battaient', 'v', '3p'), (u'battons', 'v', '1p'), ...}

Comment: Code corrected in post about the indentation!

Comment: And for the copy thing, sorry I meant I create a double of the original.

Comment: The wall of text is lovely and everything, but I'd be much more inclined to help if you'd provided some _self-contained_ code, it's inputs, and both the outputs it gives and the ones you want. Or, since you say it sometimes work, _code that demonstrates it both working and not working_. As it is, I can't easily see what the problem is.

Comment: I haven't finished reading the whole story yet (once I've finished Jules Verne, I might try this next), but "ONLY when this bit of code is called from within a function" leads me to think your altering the array inside the function, without meaning to. Your piece of code at the end shows you're returning a list, so you probably don't mean to alter the original one. So pass a copy when you call `createVariants`.

Comment: I think here might be your problem: `resList[i][idx] = verbFlex[i]`. `resList[i]` is `expr_listFormat`, and you alter it's contents with the next `[idx]`. (a few lines above, your comments says "make a copy ...", but you do *not* make a copy, you just put the original array into `resList`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put my comments in an answer, so it's a bit easier to parse. I haven't tested it, because I can't; not without knowing what exactly are your input variables. So this is some guess work.

You say: "ONLY when this bit of code is called from within a function",
which leads me to think your altering the array inside the function, without meaning to. 
Your piece of code at the end shows you're returning a list, so you probably don't mean to alter the original one.

Let's look at the code of the function:

```
def createVariants(expr_listFormat, flexDict):
    for sublist in expr_listFormat:
        if sublist[3] and sublist[1] == "v":
            verbFlex = []  ## list of flexions, each flexion being a tuple like ('bats', 'v', '2s')
            resList = []  ## list of copies of the expression
        for flexion in flexDict[sublist[0]]:
            resList.append(expr_listFormat)  ## making a copy of the original for each flexion
```

No! You don't make a copy, you insert `expr_listFormat` as is. Which is the variable you put as one of the arguments to your function.

```
            verbFlex.append(flexion)  ## list of flexions
        for i in range(len(verbFlex)):
            resList[i][idx] = verbFlex[i]
```

And here you change it: `resList[i]` is `expr_listFormat`, so you're actually doing `expr_listFormat[idx] = verbFlex[i]`. You've now altered `expr_listFormat`.

To avoid this, the easiest is to pass a copy when calling the function:

```
createVariants(inputList[:], inputdict)
```

Or change the line in the function code

```
resList.append(expr_listFormat[:])  ## making a copy of the original for each flexion
```